# How to conditionally close a jQuery Overlay?

Tags: jquery, callback, overlay, conditional-statements

I am providing a custom close button for a jQuery Overlay.
When this button is clicked, I want to validate a form inside the Overlay, and close the Overlay *if and only if* the form is valid.

Example (doesn't work... always close no matter what)

```
$('.trigger[rel]').overlay(
{
   close: '.ovclosebutton',
   onClose: function()
   {
      if( validateSomething() )
          this.getOverlay().close();
      else
          displayErrorInOverlayButDontCloseIt(); 
   }
});
```

How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are using [jQuery tools overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html).  Looking at the event methods you probably need to tie into `onBeforeClose` instead of `onClose`

> `onBeforeClose`    before the overlay is closed 
>   `onClose`  when the overlay is closed

Not sure if this will work with the plugin but might be a start for some pseudo code.

```
$('.trigger[rel]').overlay(
{
   close: '.ovclosebutton',
   onBeforeClose: function()
   {
      if( validateSomething() )
          return true; //let the overlay close by default.
      else{
          displayErrorInOverlayButDontCloseIt();
          return false; //block the close
      }
   }
});
```

Looking at the [event refrence](http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/scripting.html#events) you should be able to cancel the close using `onBeforeClose`

> Before and after events These tools
>   provide both the onBefore event which
>   occurs before some action is taken and
>   the on event that occurs at the time
>   (or after) an action takes place. You
>   can have custom functionality bound to
>   these events. All tools provide such
>   events and they share a common naming
>   policy. The onBefore event provides
>   you with the possibility of cancelling
>   the action.

Comment: True ! The `onClose` event is triggered just after the closing. Use `onBeforeClose` instead.

Comment: Thank you !  My mistake was that I was not returning anything from the onBeforeClose function.  When I modified it as Mark & Akarun suggested, it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to know about this can be found here

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/#